# UriBuilder namespace

Tags: c#, uribuilder

Before I ask my question I must say that I read `MSDN` website before and used `Using System;` as `namespace` for class.

When I use the class `UriBuilder` with `Using System` in my code,it is dis-active. What is the namespace of this class?

I am using visual studio 2008 and my operation system is windows 7.

The sample of code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static public string AssemblyDirectory
    {
        get
        {
            string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = (uri.Path);
            return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `UriBuilder` with `global::System.UriBuilder`?

Comment: Well, you need to have a reference to `System.dll`, but I don't see how you could *not* have a reference to that seeing that it's a windows forms application etc. What does "dis-active" mean? Does it not compile? What error does it print out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This MSDN link shows you which namespace to use and the assembly you will need to reference to utilize this class for each version of the .NET framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.design.urlbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks @DaveRead, But I read this page before. Must I add special reference to my project?

Comment: Yes. You need to add an assembly reference to System.Design.dll, as it tells you in the documentation.